# How to include json object in php CURL

Tags: php, android, json, curl

I'm using the 42Matters API to try and pull lists of apps from the Android Market Place. I'm looking at [this](https://42matters.com/api/advanced-query-api) API and it says under Request payload:

> "Design your query in the App Market Explorer for Android and copy its JSON representation as POST request body to the Advanced Query API endpoint."

I took their sample query at the bottom and have been trying to figure out how I'm supposed to include it in my URL to retrieve the results. Here's what I have so far:

query.json

```
{
  "query": {
    "name": "Most Popular Apps",
    "platform": "android",
    "query_params": {
      "sort": "number_ratings",
      "from": 0,
      "num": 100,
      "i18n_lang": [],
      "cat_int": [
        "14",
        "12"
      ],
      "content_rating": [],
      "sort_order": "desc",
      "downloads_lte": "",
      "downloads_gte": ""
    }
  }
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $jsonQuery = fopen("query.json", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $query = fread($jsonQuery, filesize("query.json"));
    var_dump(json_encode($query));


    // var_dump(json_encode($jsonQuery));       
        $url = "https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/query.json?access_token=tokenNum&".urlencode(json_encode($query));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //don't print info to screen!
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));  
        var_dump($result);
?>
```

The end result keeps returning a "Missing Query"

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get

Comment: You don't need to use json_encode here.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you might have figured out the issue (send data as POST and don't need to json_encode it) but please have a look at our **updated** documentations at this link:

[https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/advanced-query-api](https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/advanced-query-api?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=31280458)

I hope this helps, otherwise feel free to get in touch with me. I have lots of experience in the mobile app business so I'm sure I'll be able to point you in the right direction.

Best regards,

Andrea