# Retrieving web content multiple times simultaneously in php

Tags: php, curl, web-deployment

I use curl to retrieve web content from another site but there is two problems;
first, it takes an average 4 sec period to retrieve the contents and I don't know if there is any way to reduce it; second, some times remote server returns a short error message instead of full content.

I was thinking it would very efficient to send 3 request simultaneously, then check the first received response to see if it's an error or not and check the second respond if the first one was an error. by this method it would not be need to wait a full 4 secs to get retry response if the first one was error. but I don't know if it's possible to doing it.

It would be very appreciated if any one write a simple code to send multiple request simultaneously. 
Here is my initial code:

```
<?php
    $then = microtime(true);
    $url='http://www.example.com/StockInformationHandler.ashx?{%22Type%22:%22getstockprice%22,%22la%22:%22En%22,%22arr%22:%22IRO1LKGH0001,IRO1MADN0001,IRO1KAVR0001,IRO1BHMN0001,IRO1PNBA0001,IRO3ASPZ0001,IRO1IKCO0001,IRO1BANK0001,IRO1IKHR0001,IRO1BDAN0001,IRO1SHND0001,IRO1NBEH0001,IRO1PIAZ0001,IRO1RSAP0001,IRO3DTDZ0001,IRO1TSBE0001,IRO1NAFT0001,IRO1PKHA0001,IRO1AZAB0001,IRO3BMAZ0001,IRO1BANS0001,IRO1BAFG0001,IRO1TAYD0001,IRO1GDIR0001,IRO1SPDZ0001,IRO1NALM0001,IRO1TOSA0001,IRO1BSDR0001,IRO1ZMYD0001,IRO1SBEH0001,IRO3SMBZ0001,IRO1PASN0001,IRO1SPAH0001,IRO1PNES0001,IRO1ALIR0001,IRO1MKBT0001,IRO1FKHZ0001,IRO1RENA0001,IRO1SSHR0001,IRO1PKER0001,IRO1SAHD0001,IRO1BTEJ0001,IRO1DADE0001,IRO1PARK0001,IRO1SKRN0001,IRO1FOLD0001,IRO3KHMZ0001,IRO1NASI0001,IRO3FAYZ0001,IRO1ALMR0001,IRO1NSTH0001,IRO1BMLT0001,IRO1TKSM0001,IRO1AYEG0001,IRO1GTSH0001,IRO1COMB0001,IRO3IMFZ0001,IRO1INDM0001,IRO1DSOB0001,IRO3NPSZ0001,IRO1BPAS0001,IRO1PKOD0001,IRO1OFST0001,IRO3NOLZ0001,IRO1RIIR0001,IRO1ATDM0001,IRO1SNMA0001,IRO1VSIN0001,IRO1MNGZ0001,IRO3PSKZ0001,IRO3KRMZ0001,IRO1AMIN0001,IRO1PRDZ0001,IRO1GLOR0001,IRO1SAJN0001,IRO3BGHZ0001,IRO1PAKS0001,IRO1SIPA0001,IRO1PLKK0001,IRO1KSHJ0001,IRO3BDYZ0001,IRO1LEAB0001,IRO1KHSH0001,IRO1KRIR0001,IRO1PKLJ0001,IRO1HTOK0001,IRO1BPST0001,IRO1TAMI0001,IRO1DTIP0001,IRO1SAND0001,IRO1SHPZ0001,IRO1SHKR0001,IRO1CHAR0001,IRO1ALBZ0001,IRO1LMIR0001,IRO1TRIR0001,IRO3ETLZ0001,IRO1CRBN0001,IRO1SAKH0001,IRO3MSZ93011,IRO1NSAZ0001,IRO3BLSZ0001,IRO1MSMI0001,IRO1TMEL0001,IRO1BALB0001,IRO1LZIN0001,IRO3RFNZ0001,IRO1ABAD0001,IRO1LSMD0001,IRO1DPAK0001,IRO1PLAK0001,IRO1MAVA0001,IRO1GSBE0001,IRO3BIPZ0001,IRO1PSIR0001,IRO1BALI0001,IRO1LIRZ0001,IRO3PKSH0001,IRO1NOVN0001,IRO3GRDZ0001,IRO3PMRZ0001,IRO1ROZD0001,IRO1PABD0001,IRO1SSEP0001,IRO1SGRB0001,IRO1NSPS0001,IRO3ARFZ0001,IRO1GNBO0001,IRO1KHAZ0001,IRO1KIMI0001,IRO1SSIN0001,IRO1PETR0001,IRO1BSTE0001,IRO3DSOZ0001,IRO1TSHE0001,IRO1NMOH0001,IRO1SBAH0001,IRO1TMKH0001,IRO3MNOZ0001,IRO1MAPN0001,IRO1SGAZ0001,IRO1MAGS0001,IRO3PRZZ0001,IRO1HSHM0001,IRO3MSZ93021,IRO1KGND0001,IRO1SGOS0001,IRO1SISH0001,IRO1SKER0001,IRO1KCHI0001,IRO3MRJZ0001,IRO1FRVR0001,IRO1GHEG0001,IRO1KRTI0001,IRO1RINM0001,IRO1GHAT0001,IRO1PSHZ0001,IRO1PNTB0001,IRO1KNRZ0001,IRO1BOTA0001,IRO1GOLG0001,IRT3SATF0001,IRO3AFRZ0001,IRR3ASPZ0101,IRO7ARMP0001,IRO3ZF090001,IRT3SSAF0001,IRT3CASF0001,IRO1ASIA0001,IRO1CONT0001,IRO7BHEP0001,IRO1BAKH0001,IRO1KALZ0001,IRO1KBLI0001,IRO1TRNS0001,IRO1KTAK0001,IRO3BSMZ0001,IRR3BSMZ0101,IRO1SWIC0001,IRO1LAPS0001,IRO1JOSH0001,IRO1MOTJ0001,IRR1MOTJ0101,IRO7MILP0001,IRO1NIRO0001,IRO7BHPP0001,IRO3ZF180001,IRO1ARTA0001,IRO1IPAR0001,IRO1YASA0001,IRO1PASH0001,IRO1TAIR0001,IRO3ZF340001,IRO3ZF140001,IRO7IPTP0001,IRR7IPTP0101,IRO3ZF280001,IRO1DRKH0001,IRO3ZF040001,IRO7SHIP0001,IRO1BARZ0001,IRO1PLST0001,IRO1GAZL0001,IRO1PTAP0001,IRO7HPKP0001,IRO1PIRN0001,IRO7GSIP0001,IRO1MOZI0001,IRO3MSZ93031,IRO3MSZ93041,IRO3MSZ93051,IRO3MSZ93061,IRO3MSZ93071,IRO3MSZ93081,IRO3MSZ93091,IRO3MSZ93101,IRO3MSZ93111,IRO3MSZ93121,IRO3MSZ94011,IRO3MSZ94021,IRO3MSZ94031,IRO3MSZ94041,IRO3MSZ94051,IRO1FROZ0001,IRO1GSKE0001,IRO7NARP0001,IRO1TKNO0001,IRO1MNMH0001,IRO3TORZ0001,IRO1SESF0001,IRO3PMTZ0001,IRO1PMSZ0001,IRO3OSHZ0001,IRO3SGDZ0001,IRO3CGRZ0001,IRO1OFRS0001,IRO1MSKN0001,IRO3PJMZ0001,IRO7BPRP0001,IRO1FIBR0001,IRO1KMSH0001,IRO1KSKA0001,IRO3ZF160001,IRO1NEOP0001,IRO1HJPT0001,IRO3KHZZ0001,IRO7RAHP0001,IRO1HFRS0001,IRO1KFJR0001,IRO7BHKP0001,IRO1AZIN0001,IRO1ATIR0001,IRO1SZPO0001,IRO1RTIR0001,IRO1RADI0001,IRR1CHAR0101,IRO3ZF030001,IRO1FNAR0001,IRO7SDRP0001,IRO1IDOC0001,IRO1KFAN0001,IRO1GOST0001,IRO1LENT0001,IRO1MHKM0001,IRO1MSTI0001,IRO1MNSR0001,IRR1IKCO0101,IRO1MESI0001,IRO1DABO0001,IRO1DOSE0001,IRO1DALZ0001,IRO1PDRO0001,IRO1TMVD0001,IRO1THDR0001,IRO1DJBR0001,IRO7DHVP0001,IRO1DAML0001,IRO1DRZK0001,IRO1DZAH0001,IRO1DSIN0001,IRO1DDPK0001,IRO1ABDI0001,IRO1DFRB0001,IRO1FTIR0001,IRO1DKSR0001,IRO1EXIR0001,IRO1DLGM0001,IRO7PDHP0001,IRO1IRDR0001,IRO3ZOBZ0001,IRO1INFO0001,IRO1EPRS0001,IRO1TKIN0001,IRO1RKSH0001,IRO3ZF120001,IRO3ZF240001,IRO3PZGZ0001,IRO7ZNJP0001,IRO3ZAGZ0001,IRO1AZRT0001,IRO1SDAB0001,IRO1SADB0001,IRO1SURO0001,IRO7IRNP0001,IRO7CBBP0001,IRO1SBOJ0001,IRO3SBZZ0001,IRO1SBHN0001,IRO1PRMT0001,IRO1STEH0001,IRO7SASP0001,IRO1SKHS0001,IRO1SKAZ0001,IRO7SEKP0001,IRO3DBRZ0001,IRO1SDST0001,IRO1SDOR0001,IRO1SROD0001,IRR1SSHR0101,IRO1SIMS0001,IRO1SEFH0001,IRO1SSOF0001,IRB3SSHZ9241,IRO1SFRS0001,IRO1SFKZ0001,IRO1FRDO0001,IRO1SFAS0001,IRO1SFNO0001,IRO1SGEN0001,IRO3SKBZ0001,IRO1SKOR0001,IRO1SMAZ0001,IRO3IBKZ0001,IRO7IENP0001,IRO1SSNR0001,IRO1SHZG0001,IRO1SHGN0001,IRO3SYSZ0001,IRO1SEIL0001,IRO1AMLH0001,IRO3PNLZ0001,IRO1BMPS0001,IRO1PPAM0001,IRO3PTRZ0001,IRO1THSH0001,IRO1TOPI0001,IRO1DODE0001,IRO1SHRG0001,IRO1ZNGN0001,IRO1SEPP0001,IRO7STNP0001,IRO1TSAL0001,IRO1SHSI0001,IRO1PESF0001,IRO1PFRB0001,IRO1SHFS0001,IRR1SHFS0101,IRO1PFAN0001,IRO7PKBP0001,IRO1KAFF0001,IRO1NKOL0001,IRO7SHLP0001,IRO1NPRS0001,IRO1VASH0001,IRT1CSNF0001,IRO1KLBR0001,IRO1BENN0001,IRO1LPAK0001,IRO1MINO0001,IRO1CHCH0001,IRO1KDPS0001,IRO1DMOR0001,IRO1SLMN0001,IRO1SPKH0001,IRO1SPPE0001,IRO1SHAD0001,IRO7MINP0001,IRO1GORJ0001,IRO1GCOZ0001,IRO1MRGN0001,IRO1MRAM0001,IRO1RNAB0001,IRO1NOSH0001,IRO1KIVN0001,IRO1MARK0001,IRO1KSIM0001,IRO1ALTK0001,IRO1SAMA0001,IRO1BAHN0001,IRO1BMAS0001,IRO1BIRI0001,IRO1SPTA0001,IRO1JAMD0001,IRO1FAJR0001,IRO1JSHO0001,IRO1FKAS0001,IRO1FRIS0001,IRO1TFKR0001,IRO3ZF100001,IRO3KZIZ0001,IRO1SEPA0001,IRO1LSDD0001,IRO1SORB0001,IRO1SOLI0001,IRO1LAMI0001,IRO7FANP0001,IRO1NGFO0001,IRO1FVAN0001,IRO1FAIR0001,IRO1GPRS0001,IRO1GPSH0001,IRO3CHRZ0001,IRO1GGAZ0001,IRO1GSHI0001,IRO1GHND0001,IRO3GHSZ0001,IRO1GESF0001,IRO1GMRO0001,IRO1GNJN0001,IRO1ABGN0001,IRO3ZF200001,IRT3SSKF0001,IRO7PKZP0001,IRO1KESF0001,IRO1BAMA0001,IRO1ITAL0001,IRO1IRGC0001,IRO1KPRS0001,IRO1CHML0001,IRO1CHIR0001,IRO1KHFZ0001,IRO1DMVN0001,IRO1TSRZ0001,IRO1ROOI0001,IRO1SINA0001,IRR1SINA0101,IRO1ARDK0001,IRO1PSER0001,IRO1KSAD0001,IRO3KSGZ0001,IRO1TBAS0001,IRO1SHQZ0001,IRO1ALVN0001,IRO1NILO0001,IRO1BHSM0001,IRO1SHMD0001,IRO1VARZ0001,IRO3KBCZ0001,IRO1ASAL0001,IRO1AZMA0001,IRO1PELC0001,IRO1PYAM0001,IRO1JJNM0001,IRO1LKPS0001,IRO1SRMA0001,IRO1KMOA0001,IRO1IAGM0001,IRO3KARZ0001,IRO1BMEL0001,IRO7PMMP0001,IRO3ZF220001,IRR3KHMZ0101,IRO3MIHZ0001,IRO1BROJ0001,IRO1PTOS0001,IRO3ZF060001,IRO1MRIN0001,IRO7BNOP0001,IRO7NIRP0001,IRO3ZF080001,IRO1HMRZ0001,IRO7VHYP0001,IRR1ALBZ0101,IRO1OIMC0001,IRO1TAZB0001,IRO7KARP0001,IRO1BIME0001,IRO1BPAR0001,IRO1DARO0001,IRO1TGOS0001,IRO1TOKA0001,IRO3BKHZ0001,IRO3BMDZ0001,IRO3ZMNZ0001,IRO1SSAP0001,IRO1SDID0001,IRO1SKBV0001,IRR1SKBV0101,IRO7SNAP0001,IRO7SHOP0001,IRO1GBEH0001,IRO7TKDP0001,IRO1KRAF0001,IRO7KOSP0001,IRO3IRNZ0001,IRO7BVMP0001,IRO1MELT0001,IRO1GMEL0001,IRO1SNRO0001,IRO1NIKI0001,IRR3ETLZ0101,IRR1BARZ0101,IRO1KVRZ0001,IRR1TRIR0101,IRR3ZNDZ0101,IRR3ZNDZ0101,IRR1KSKA0101,IRR1DALZ0101,IRO3BLKZ0001,IRR1TKIN0101,IRO1KHOC0001,IRO1CIDC0001,IRR1PNTB0101,IRR1PRDZ0101,IRR3PTRZ0101,IRO3LIAZ0001,IRR1GNJN0101,IRO3TBSZ0001,IRR1PKER0101,IRR1SGAZ0101,IRO1BVMA0001,IRO1MOBN0001,IRR1BMEL0101,IRO3FOHZ0001,IRR1BPAS0101,IRO3BHLZ0001,,%22}';
    $ch=curl_init();
    $timeout=15;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    // Get URL content
    $lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $now = microtime(true);
    echo sprintf("Elapsed:  %f", $now-$then);
    $lines_string;
    echo "\r\n";
?>
```

Comment: post your tried code..

Comment: Are you sure that the site API doesn't required a POST request instead of a GET req? Your query string seems a json string of 6906 characters...

Comment: Thanks you fusion for your notice, does it make any difference in efficiency?

Comment: @Zanyar There's not a universal response, but your url is unusual. Some servers have limit to length requests. This could be the cause of errors, but it's not sure. Can you check the API specifications of the site? Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: dear @fusion3k , you are right it just returns response for half of variables (just respond to first 4000 characters) but it does not seem to be the reason for casual errors; by the way, I tried to fix it by changing the code to send a json post request as this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get), but it does not work for me yet