# How to pass JSON Data Using PHP CURL in WePay API?

Tags: php, json, api, curl, wepay

I want to use WePay reports API for reporting purpose to show WePay transaction and withdrawal information in my custom application . When I call Wepayreports api I have faced some issues in passing JSON Data using PHP CURL.

My Code like below:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "type" => "merchant_transactions",
    "resource" => array(
        "object_type" => "account",
        "object_id" => 634303761
    )
);
$ch = curl_init('https://stage.wepayapi.com/v2/report/create'); // URL of the call
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8');
// execute the api call
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// display the json response
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

When i am trying to call this in API Calls receive data like below

```
{"{\"type\":\"merchant_transactions\",\"resource\":{\"object_type\":\"account\",\"object_id\":\"1776251645\"}}":""}
```

But i need to send data like below:

```
{"type":"merchant_transactions","resource":{"object_type":"account","object_id":"1776251645"}}
```

For you kind reference here is the link of WePay API Documantation.[WePay Reports API](https://developer.wepay.com/api-calls/reports)

If you have any other alternative solution for solving this issue please let me know.

Can anyone help me on this regards?Any kind of help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use their PHP SDK i.e a wrapper around their API for PHP. https://github.com/wepay/php-sdk

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and set its value to `application/json`. And send actual json string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl and PHP - how can I pass a json through curl by PUT,POST,GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading WePay Report Final Code like below.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "type" => "merchant_transactions",
    "resource" => array(
        "object_type" => "account",
        "object_id" => 634303761
    ),
    "callback_uri"=>"https://example.com/report/ipn"
);
$data = json_encode($data);

$access_token = 'STAGE_5d93d1cfb8a47da7f726fd0cacfeda5ghfhgfhfgh0f74adbc089e1d36d1dc1ccc5a57aafd92b'; // access_token received from /oauth2/token call
$ch = curl_init('https://stage.wepayapi.com/v2/report/create'); // URL of the call
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8');
// execute the api call
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// display the json response
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

API response like below.

```
Array
(
    [report_id] => 23684078
    [user_id] => 22866774
    [resource] => Array
        (
            [object_type] => account
            [object_id] => 634303761
        )

    [type] => merchant_transactions
    [advanced_options] => Array
        (
            [disable_email] => 1
        )

    [state] => processing
    [request_time] => 1476023145
    [expires_time] => 
    [callback_uri] => https://example.com/report/ipn
    [report_uri] => 
)
```

This is very useful solution to integrate WePay Reports API In you custom application. This solution working for me 100%. If you have face any kind of trouble please let me know. i am ready to answer.

Comment: Instead of writing your own answer(which is exactly same), you must accept my answer. As it was the one which helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from https://developer.wepay.com/general/api-call

> Call arguments should be passed as JSON in the body of the request
>   with content-type HTTP header set to application/json. Make sure to
>   set a valid User-Agent header (our SDKs do this for you). The
>   User-Agent can be anything, but keep it informative. For example:
>   “WePay v2 PHP SDK v0.0.9”.

And your answer lies here:
[Curl and PHP - how can I pass a json through curl by PUT,POST,GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get)

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "type" => "merchant_transactions",
    "resource" => array(
        "object_type" => "account",
        "object_id" => 634303761
    )
);
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://stage.wepayapi.com/v2/report/create'); // URL of the call
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8');
// execute the api call
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// display the json response
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This information is very helpful for me.