# How to post curl using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using an API in which CURL is required for use.

Here is the code:

```
    <?

curl -v -X POST https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \ 
-H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
-d '


{
"amount": 11,
"recurringTransaction": "ECOMMERCE",
"merchantTransactionId": 3,
"softDescriptor": "DescTest",
"cardHolderInfo": {
    "firstName": "test first name",
    "lastName": "test last name"
},
"currency": "GBP",
"creditCard": {
    "expirationYear": 2018,
    "securityCode": 837,
    "expirationMonth": "02",
    "cardNumber": 4263982640269299
},
"cardTransactionType": "AUTH_CAPTURE"
}'


?>
```

Please provide an exact conversion of the CURL code to make it work within PHP.

Comment: what do you mean by "make this code work"?

Comment: You can't just put PHP tags around any code and have it be PHP. Look at the manual. Also enable short tags if you're going to use `<?` for opening. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @emaillenin I mean how can I make the CURL work in a PHP document. I mean how can I convert it to be PHP friendly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: @chris85 No, I need an exact conversion please. I am not familiar with CURL at all

Comment: I think you can probably start with the PHP manual to tell you how it works. Try something then come back if you get stuck.

Comment: SO is not a conversion site. Try craigslist, freelancer, or some other contracting site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get)

Comment: @chris85 If you're not gonna help with the question, your comments aren't needed. Thanks

Comment: My comments are to help you formulate a question appropriate for SO users who are donating there **free** time to help you.

Comment: @chris85 The question was appropriate and clear enough to receive an adequate answer below. It isn't your job to decide which questions are appropriate. Also, no one is being forced to answer my question and donate their time to it. It is actually people like you who ruin the community by trying to make people feel bad for asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an equivalent PHP curl call would be

```
<?php
$data=array(
"amount"=>11,
"recurringTransaction"=>"ECOMMERCE",
"merchantTransactionId"=>3,
"softDescriptor"=>"DescTest",
"cardHolderInfo"=>array(
    "firstName"=>"test first name",
    "lastName"=>"test last name"
),
"currency"=>"GBP",
"creditCard"=>array(
    "expirationYear"=>2018,
    "securityCode"=>837,
    "expirationMonth"=>"02",
    "cardNumber"=>4263982640269299
),
"cardTransactionType"=>"AUTH_CAPTURE"
);
$data_json=json_encode($data,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,
CURLOPT_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_URL=>'https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=',
),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data_json,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'curl/7.50.1',
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

[image]