# cURL with PHP passing data with PUT

Tags: php, curl, put

I would like  to curl thru PHP using PUT method to a remote server. And stream to a file.

My normal command would look like this :

```
curl http://192.168.56.180:87/app -d "data=start" -X PUT
```

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get) on SO .

**EDIT :**

Using Vitaly and Pedro Lobito comments I changed my code to :

```
$out_file = "logging.log";
$fp = fopen($out_file, "w");

$ch = curl_init();
$urlserver='http://192.168.56.180:87/app';
$data = array('data=start');
$ch = curl_init($urlserver);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

But still not Ok.

When My I have this response using curl :

```
 192.168.56.154 - - [04/May/2017 17:14:55] "PUT /app HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And I have this response using the php above:

```
 192.168.56.154 - - [04/May/2017 17:07:55] "PUT /app HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/1342760/1566113 this is what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the POST string incorrectly

```
$data = array('data=start');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
```

In this case, you've already built your string, so just include it

```
$data = 'data=start';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

`http_build_query` is only when you have a `key => value` array and need to convert it to a POST string

Comment: That did the Job. thanks. I am messed up with the "array('data=start')"; I though I had to specify the type ( following other SO thread) but I guess I was wrong ! . Good to Know !

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you save the curl output directly to a file? i.e.:

```
$out_file = "/path/to/file";
$fp = fopen($out_file, "w");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

**Note:**
When you ask a question about an error, always include the **error log**. To enable error reporting, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script.

Comment: I got the "192.168.56.154 - - [04/May/2017 16:52:56] "PUT / HTTP/1.1" 404 -" on my target web server. I guess the issue comes from the command I sent.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");`

Comment: I edited my initial post. I confirm, I do not use : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); Any clues ?