# Magento 2 Rest Api - Associative Array In Request Param

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2

I am trying to create custom Api in magneto2. Its a POST CALL, in which i am trying to send associative array like below,

```
{
    "data": {       
        "testData": {
            "title": "Test 01",         
            "place": {
                "key": "value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the above format i am giving the param annotation as `string[]`. Its working If i didn't pass `place` data in it. But if i am passing `place` data its throwing error like below,

```
Array to string conversion
```

Actual problem is i am not able to pass associative array in request param. Can anyone please help me on this?

I tried by creating an custom object type also. In that too i can give `string[]` type only. So i cannot add more and more json data in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create array in PHP and use function to encode to json for e.g.

```
    $arr= array( 'val1'=>array('your val1', 'your val2'),
    'val2'=>array('your val1', 'your val2'),
    );

    $data = json_encode($arr);
// if you want to set in url
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
$client->setRawData($data, 'application/json')->request('POST');
```

you will need to use json_decode to get your values later.
Hope this helps!

Comment: yes. thats fine. But any other option to pass json data direcly?

Comment: your emai id please?

Comment: why you need another option?

for sending directly, below link can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get