# PHP I want to send the post data by Codeigniter, How to make the post request?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am developing the web server using other service by CodeIgniter.
So I am going to send the data to the service using api calling.
But I have a issue to make the request.

This is the data what I want to send.

```
$datastr = 'proc_name=customer_upd&params={ 
"proc_info":
{ 
    "proc_division":"U"
}, 
"data":[{ 
    "table_name":"Customer", 
    "rows":[ {
                    "itemId" : "12231551",
                    "lastName" : "ads",
                    "firstName" : "fds"
   } ] 
}] 
}'
```

I made my code for this.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://webapi.ooo.com/access/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastr);
curl_exec($curl);
```

But this is not work.
I am tested by postman, but it works well.
I think there is a issue to make the post request.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you to read this blog: https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But my problem is "'proc_name=customer_upd&params={ "
how can i make the data for this part?
I think this is not array data...
Please help me..

Comment: What is your API code that deciphers this look like?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the API code.

Comment: Ok then, so how about the documentation for it. You have to know that because you are posting data to it. So you would have to know what to be sending to it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are sending query string, instead, send only data in the key-value pair to the web service you are consuming. Check in which form web service is accepting the data. First, check web service from postman

Here is an example,

$data = array("key_1" =>value_1 , "key_2" =>"value_2" , "key_3" =>"value_3" , "key_4" =>"value_4" , "key_5" =>"value_5" );

```
 function api($url,$api,$data)
 {
                $ch = curl_init();
                $webservicelink = $url.$api;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webservicelink);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type: application/json'));      
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                return json_decode($result, true);
 }
```