# How to send JSON data in body with header using post method in PHP(cURL)

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

I'm try to below code for send request in post method with json data and header constant type : application/json

```
$ch_get = curl_init($url_get);
        $jsonData1_get_r = array(
            'customerMobileNo'=>'9040845440',
            'recipientMobileNo'=>'7008565316',
            'recipientName'=>'Name Test Test',
            'accountNo'=>'5928374737328009',
            'bankName'=>'HDFC',
            'accIfsc'=>'HDFC0002058',
            'transactionType'=>'IMPS',
            'amount'=>'100'
            );
        $jsonDataEncoded_get = json_encode($jsonData1_get_r);

        curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded_get);
        curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: '.$token.''));
        curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $result_get = curl_exec($ch_get);
        curl_close($ch_get);
```

when use above code below error comes

**Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported**

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried setting both headers at once, in the same array? The way it's currently used, it would seem that the `Content-Type` is being overriden.

Comment: Something like `curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: '.$token));`

Comment: [I think you must look at here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use below code to achieve your goal

```
$jsonData1_get_r = array(
        'customerMobileNo'=>'9040845440',
        'recipientMobileNo'=>'7008565316',
        'recipientName'=>'Name Test Test',
        'accountNo'=>'5928374737328009',
        'bankName'=>'HDFC',
        'accIfsc'=>'HDFC0002058',
        'transactionType'=>'IMPS',
        'amount'=>'100'
        ); 

$jsonDataEncoded_get  = json_encode($jsonData1_get_r );
$ch_get = curl_init($url_get);
curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded_get );
curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($ch_get, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Authorization: ' . $token)                                                                       

);
```

Hope you this will helps you !!

Thanks & Regards